# Prove equality vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, let $\varphi \in$ End$_K(V)$ be a $K$-endomorphism of $V$, and let $S$ be a $K$-basis of $V$. Prove that for every polynomial $f \in K[X]$ one has the equality:

$$M_{S,S}(f(\varphi))=f(M_{S,S}(\varphi)).$$

My question is do I have to show that $M_{S,S}$ is linearly independent? And how do I do that?

Comment: What is $M_{S,S}$?

Comment: If, as I think, $M_{S,S}(\varphi)$ is the matrix of $\varphi$ with respect to $S$, then your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f = \sum a_i x^i$. Then:
$$M_{S,S}(f(\varphi)) = M_{S,S}\left(\sum a_i \varphi^i\right) = \sum a_i M_{S,S} (\varphi^i) = \sum a_i M_{S,S}(\varphi)^i = f(M_{S,S}(\varphi))$$